# Get administrator privilegs in Qt during runtime

Tags: windows, qt, elevated-privileges

My Qt-based application needs sometomes administrator privilegs on Windows.

Is it possible, to start the application with user's privilegs and switch to admin-privilegs when needed at run-time?

Comment: I don't think so. You should start it with admin privileges.

Comment: check [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/26725/how-to-ask-for-administrator-privileges-in-windows/2) thread - it seems that its possible and you have many options..

Comment: @perencia It should be possible. The most Installers do that.